# c segfault due to wrong pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

This is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getinfo(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, char **s);

int main(){
    unsigned int len_max = 8;
    unsigned int current_size = 0;
    char *pStr = malloc(len_max);
    if(pStr == NULL){
        perror("\nMemory allocation\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    current_size = len_max;

    printf("Inserisci hostname: ");
    getinfo(len_max, current_size, &pStr);
    printf("\nLa stringa inserita è: %s\n", pStr);
    free(pStr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getinfo(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, char **pStr){
    unsigned int i = 0;
    char c = EOF;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        *pStr[i++] = (char)c;
        if(i == b){
            b = i+a;
            if((*pStr = realloc(*pStr, b)) == NULL){
                perror("\nMemory allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    *pStr[i]='\0';
}
```

When i execute this code i got a segmentation fault when i press enter (after i've wrote the string).
I'm sure the problem is into the function (probably the problem is the *s pointer) but i don't know how to correct it...

Comment: Side note: `getchar` return `int` & not `char`. You should consider changing `c` to an `int`

Comment: oh thanks :) i've corrected the mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a precedence problem. You need to use

```
(*s)[i++] = ...
```

instead of

```
*s[i++] = ...
```

Similarly you need

```
(*s)[i]='\0';
```

When you write `*s[i]` you are indexing `s`. But you want to index `*s`, and hence require the parentheses.

I've not checked the rest of your code, but I hope this helps you on your way to debugging the rest of it, if indeed there are more errors.

Comment: @polslinux Yes I think you could be right. Myself I would try to encapsulate the method of adding an extra character to the string rather than have it intertwined with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `*s[i++] = (char)c;` try turning it into `(*s)[i++] = (char)c;` with the parenthesis around the *s. As well as `(*s)[i] = '\0'`.

Comment: I don't think so. When ever the buffer is full, you always extend it. So there is always room for 1 more character.

Comment: @Totaldowner: No wait...are you sure? Because i've done the i++ so i compare the "next i" with b! i don't compare i with the actual position :D